# How to sort the data row wise in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input----->

I need to sort the data row wise in spark. below is the input and the output.

cat,black,dog,apple,red

zoo,apple,red,blue,green

apple,green,zoo,black,walk

Output --->

apple,black,cat,dog,red

apple,blue,green,red,zoo

apple,black,green,walk,zoo

Comment: Have a look at [array_sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#array_sort)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one column per word, you first need to gather them all in one column with the function `array`. Then you can use the function `array_sort`:

```scala
scala> df.withColumn("as_list", array_sort(array(df.columns.map(col): _*))).show(truncate=false)
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+--------------------------------+
|_c0  |_c1  |_c2|_c3  |_c4  |as_list                         |
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+--------------------------------+
|cat  |black|dog|apple|red  |[apple, black, cat, dog, red]   |
|zoo  |apple|red|blue |green|[apple, blue, green, red, zoo]  |
|apple|green|zoo|black|walk |[apple, black, green, walk, zoo]|
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+--------------------------------+
```

If you words are already in a list, you can directly use `array_sort`:

```scala
scala> df.withColumn("words", array_sort(col(words))).show(truncate=false)
```